# WGET non-recursive mode

Tags: wget

I am using `wget` for Windows. I got the binaries from [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm). When I use wget, by default, it retrieves the contents of the url specified recursively. I need to get only the files present in the immediate directory. How to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify the `-l` flag to limit the depth of recursion (set it to 0: `-l 0` to only retrieve files in the top level directory.

Comment: Using -l 0 sets the recursion depth to infinity.

Answer (score 2):

Based on `wget -?` you need to add `-r` to get enable recursive get. Do you have an option set in a `.wgetrc` or `wgetrc` configuration file? (`wget` here reports which configuration files it reads when run.)

Look for a settings `reclevel` and `recursive` (that are not commented out) in the configuration file.